# NewPipe build failure due to no 'extractor' found #10432

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I'm trying to build `NewPipe` but it tells me:

`Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:extractor:v0.22.7`

I get 9 errors all of them are related to this 'extractor'. The full build log output is:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /home/elias/Android/NewPipe-0.25.2

> Task :app:createDebugVariantModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:formatKtlint UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:runCheckstyle UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:runKtlint UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug FAILED
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths FAILED
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED
> Task :app:l8DexDesugarLibDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies FAILED
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build completed with 9 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:extractor:v0.22.7.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:timeago-parser:v0.22.7.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:extractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:timeago-parser:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:extractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:timeago-parser:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:extractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:timeago-parser:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:extractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:timeago-parser:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:extractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:timeago-parser:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:extractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:timeago-parser:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

8: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:extractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:timeago-parser:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

9: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:extractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/extractor/v0.22.7/extractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/NewPipeExtractor/v0.22.7/NewPipeExtractor-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7
   > Could not find com.github.TeamNewPipe.NewPipeExtractor:timeago-parser:v0.22.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
       - https://repo.clojars.org/com/github/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/timeago-parser/v0.22.7/timeago-parser-v0.22.7.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:v0.22.7

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
24 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 15 up-to-date
```

Does anyone know what's wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I was missing a dependent project:

https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor

Enable it in `settings.gradle`.